# React Server side + Nodejs setInterval memory leaks

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, memory-leaks

In my universal react application, I'm having a react component containing **`setInterval`** in `componentWillMount` and **`clearInterval`** in `componentWillUnmount`.

Fortunately, `componentWillUnmount` not called on the server.

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.checker = setInterval(this.checkForSubscription, 2000);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.checker);
}
```

I'm suffering from crashes and memory leaks on my express server. I created heapdumps and analysis those on chrome memory tool.

Unfortunately, got no success to find memory leaks. So, when I remove the `setInterval` from server side logic by checking `typeof` for window object. I do not create any crash since then. So, I want to know the code above is the cause of memory leaks and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely migrate you method to componenDidMount which is not called on server

```
componentDidlMount(){
    this.checker = setInterval(this.checkForSubscription, 2000);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.checker);
}
```

what you can also do is using more packages like `can-use-dom`

```
import canUseDOM from 'can-use-dom';
componentWillMount(){
    canUseDOM && this.checker = setInterval(this.checkForSubscription, 2000);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.checker);
}
```

If you are using webpack you can just define an env variable in config

```
   new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        BROWSER: JSON.stringify(true),
      },
    }),
```

and use condition `process.env.BROWSER && "your code"`

Comment: I can handle this with ease by checking the existence of the window object. My question is, will it create a memory leak on node server since componentWillUnmount is not called on the server?

Comment: No, all 3 examples will not create any memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

I found it my own. The problem with above code is that it cannot call **`clearInterval`** on the server side since componentWillUnmount has not called on the server. So, it causes a memory leak on server.

Once I set the check for the existence of window object, it only called on the client side. So, **no server crash** since then.